# Plotting ECDF (empirical cumulative distribution frequencies) with R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm learning through doing here guys, so I hope this question is considered OK (I'll edit the question down as I go - I'll remove the intro etc).

I am trying to plot the empirical cumulative distribution Frequency of a data-set with 781 observations.  The data-set looks like this:

(1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
11
11
11
11
11
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
14
14
14
14
14
15
15
15
15
16
16
17
17
17
19
19
20
21
21
21
21
22
22
23
23
).

I use the following function in R (which I pulled from [r-bloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/example-7-8-plot-two-empirical-cumulative-density-functions-using-available-tools/)):

```
plot(ecdf(V1), verticals=TRUE, pch=46)
```

which produces the following graph:

[image: ECDF plot]

EDIT =====

The graph plots the the actual observation on the x-axis and the percentage of observations on the y-axis.

Thank you for your help,

slotishtype

Answer (score 1):

Well, your X-axis holds the actual value that occurred, so that is not information you want to lose (in fact, the Y axis is more indicative of the number of observations).

There are however ways to add additional axes. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
valsOfChoice<-seq(0,25, by=5) #at which x-es do you want to show the counts
cumnumAtVals<-sapply(valsOfChoice, function(vl){sum(V1<=vl)}) #calculate matching counts
```

Then after your plot, you can use:

```
axis(3, at=valsOfChoice, labels=cumnumAtVals)
```

to add a new axis to the top, holding the cumulative count in your dataset.

Comment: Thanks a million @Nick Sabbe, I now realise my mistake.  I really want to be able to say that 50% of the population make up x amount of the culmative totals.  So, I think I really should be using cumsum instead... So I did this "plot(cumsum(V1))", which gives me a different graph (one that makes a bit more sense).  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To be blunt, the plot you posted looks correct to me. Your data set hasn't been "reduced" to 25 variables - you only have *values* of the data up that far (technically only up to 23, but whose counting?). That's what that plot should show - as the value of your variable rises from 0 to 25, what percentage of the distribution is at that point or below. Your whole data is baked into the fact that the Y-axis goes from 0 to 1.

Basically, while you can plot what you're asking to plot, it's not so much a CDF at that point.

Comment: You're right, I realised my mistake when reading over nick's answer. I think I want a cumsum with percentages as opposed to a ECDF, but I am unsure of the difference. I'll edit my answer anyhow.

Comment: Might you be looking for a Density Plot, like what's covered here: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html ?

Comment: I think I am looking at the wrong thing alright.  This is a distribution of user activity in system we have.  Each observation is a users activity in the last month.  So user 1 submitted one post while user 781 submitted 23.  I want to present simple ratios like 50% of users contributed 50% of posts (similar to pareto's rule (80/20) which is not observable here).  It helps to give a simple and understandable breakdown of activity but I think I am getting a little confused between approaches.